# LARAVEL - How to get attribute of a model

Tags: sql, laravel, model, eloquent

How can I've get  the name of a type for each categorie of products ?

Exemple 
Categorie: CAT1 / CAT2.
Product: name1 (type: type1, type_id & categorie_id foreign key)
         name2(type: type2)
type: type1
         type2

It's for make a menu of categorie with the types for "sub-menu" for this categorie (foreach)

I've tried this, but not work (Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$type).  Just $cat->produit work but this is not what I want :

```
$categories = Categorie::All();        

@foreach ($categories as $cat)   
               {{$cat->nom}}
               <ul>
                   @foreach ($cat->produit->type as $type)
                         <li><a href="#">{{$type->nom}}</a></li>                                               
                   @endforeach
              </ul>
@endforeach
```

[TYPE] 1,n(have)1,1 [PRODUCT] 1,1(To-belong)1,n [CATEGORIE]

Product

```
public function Categorie()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Categorie');
}
public function Type()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Type');
}
```

Categorie

```
public function Produit()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Produit');
}
```

Type

```
public function Produit()
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Produit');
}
```

Comment: `type` in a `Product` model is a column which contains a type name?

Comment: Product: id, name, type_id, categorie_id

Comment: thanks, I've posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most effective way to achieve this with Eloquent is this method that uses just 3 queries to get the data from DB. Then it uses the power of the Laravel collections:

```
// Get data from DB.
$categories = Categorie::with('products')->get();
$types = Type::all();

// Working with loaded collections.
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    {{ $category->name }}
    @foreach ($types->whereIn('id', $category->products->unique('type_id')->pluck('type_id')) as $type)
        {{ $type->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: I've an error with the unique: ErrorException in Builder.php line 2450:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::unique() (View:..) EDIT: you've edited your post or i'm bad and deleted one word. But it's return nothing

Comment: @emeliku that's because it should be `with('products')` not `with('product')`. Sorry for a typo.

Comment: it's $category->product->unique. But it's return nothing on view

Comment: It should be `products`

Comment: @emeliku in one of the previous comments I've told that you should use `with('products')`

Comment: Ahh, It works from the beginning !! But i've not replace the "name" in view attribute by "nom" -> it's name in french, and my database is in french !! Thanks